# Post API converts automatically to get method in Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, post, get

We are trying to hit our salesforce instance from outside using webservices. 3rd party is using post as a method. But in salesforce it is not recognized as post request.

We have used these lines in salesforce:

```
@HttpPost
global static void newRequest() {
    decimal filesize = 0;
    System.debug('line 5');
        
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    System.debug(res);
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    System.debug(req);
}
```

This method is not reached when they are sending a post method but if we change `@HttpPost` to `@HttpGet` then this piece of code got executed.
The debug is below:
`{"headers":"","httpMethod":"GET","params":"xxx","remoteAddress":"xxx.xx.xxx.xxx","requestBody":BLOB(0 bytes),"requestURI":"/generic (6 more) ...","resourcePath":"/services/apexrest/G (26 more) ..."}|`

Comment: Do you perhaps have another method in the same class that has the `@HttpPost` annotation? You can only use each annotation once in a given class.

Comment: You don't use [HTTP instead of HTTPS by any means](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263826/webservice-post-rest-api-is-receiving-as-get?rq=1)?

Comment: Check which host URL you're actually using, as well. If you hit the wrong endpoint, and a cross-domain redirect takes effect, that can convert a post to a get.

Comment: No I have only one @Http anotations.

Comment: No HTTPS is used.